# Get an xcode project's bundle id from bash

Tags: xcode, bash

How can I get the bundle identifier of the project from bash?

I've got a couple of similar xcode projects for iOS. I'm trying to get some thing done via scripts but can't figure out how to get/change project configurations (like bundle id and version) from bash.
How can I get the bundle identifier of the project from bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command inside the code directory:

`$ grep -R PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER *`

`$ grep -R PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER *|awk -F= '{print $2}'|sed 's/ //g'|sed 's/;//g'`